# In Firefox, double-clicking on a tag with href set to # but with onclick set to go to another page will effectively make us remain on the current page

Tags: javascript, firefox, anchor, double-click

Suppose we have the ff. in a.html:

```
<script>
  function onClick() {
    // Do some important stuff and then...
    location = "b.html";
  }
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="onClick();">Link</a>
```

Double-clicking on Link will trigger the event-handler onClick.  However, the second click in the double-click seems to be interpreted as another click and causes the page to jump to the named anchor.  In effect, the location isn't changed.

My questions are:

1. Is this a browser bug or feature?
2. Is there a way to work-around this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
href="javascript:void(0);"
```

instead

Comment: Side-effect: Link is never marked as visited but, since they're skinned to look like buttons, this is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.location = "b.html"`. `location` by itself has no special meaning.

The anchor jumping is unrelated. You can disable it by stopping the event.

```
function onClick(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
}

<a href="#" onclick="onClick(event)">Link</a>
```

Comment: `window` is the global object. Which means `location` is available in the global scope when written by itself. It's the same thing as `window.location`. That's why you can also do `window.window.window.location` if you like. You're actually doing the same thing for `event` in your code. It lives in the global scope and can therefore be accessed using `window.event`.

Also, your answer is missing the `return false;` variant for older browsers, and `onclick="return onClick(event);"`.

Answer (score 0):

gshankar is right

Another variant:

```
<script>
  function onClick() {
    location = "b.html";
    return false;
  }
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="return onClick();">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can point the link at the function and skip the onclick event:

```
<script>
  function onClick() {
    location = "b.html";
    return false;
  }
</script>
<a href="javascript:onClick();">Link</a>
```

Comment: Didn't mention that I'm fixing a custom tag.  User's may want to use "this" in their click handlers.  I think "this" means something else when in the "href" attrib.